# Moving Code logic from Autofac.integration.mvc to Autofac.integration.webapi

Tags: autofac

We are creating the ContainerManger which will be used by Application Engine while resolving the dependency in WebAPI. We have below mention code for fetching the current scope,considering autofac integration MVC framework

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Get current scope
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Scope</returns>
    public virtual ILifetimeScope Scope()
    {
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                return AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope;

            //when such lifetime scope is returned, you should be sure that it'll be disposed once used (e.g. in schedule tasks)
            return Container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //we can get an exception here if RequestLifetimeScope is already disposed
            //for example, requested in or after "Application_EndRequest" handler
            //but note that usually it should never happen

            //when such lifetime scope is returned, you should be sure that it'll be disposed once used (e.g. in schedule tasks)
            return Container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag);
        }
    }
```

wanted to convert it to autofac integration WebAPI framework so that same logic can be used in webapi. if you check the above code you will find AutofacDependencyResolver from autoface.integration.mvc is being used. As WebAPI is Stateless httpContext will be not available for REST API.

Can any body suggest what is the right thing to do for getting the Current Scope in the WebAPI when scope is not provided while resolving the dependency in Web API based service.

Any guidance or sample would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a `ILifetimeScope` ? Autofac should be at the top of the composition root and component should not need it. If you really need one, you can inject `ILifetimeScope` using constructor injection.

Comment: This ContainerManager is the one which will be used in different component to Resolve the dependencies at scope level instead rootscope level which is subjected to memory leak. We are using ILifetimescope because while resolving the dependencies at each component scope API user may not provide the scope. In such scenario we need the a scope hence we need the Per -Request Life time scope.

Comment: Above mention code works fine for MVC website but we are creating WebAPI Service and we need to use the object that are appropriate for WebAPI.  like AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope does not exists in Autofac.integration.WebAPI2 library that is the problem. Therefore we need the guidence on how to go about. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's :

if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    return GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope();